# How to retrieve URL for uploaded images in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using Java to upload images to an S3 bucket.  Via:

```
PutObjectResult result = s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                            BUCKET_NAME, KEY, file));
```

The `result`, however does not have a URL property from which I can access the image again.  Only 2 properties are set, `contentMd5` and `eTag`.  How can I get the URL for the uploaded file, so I can download it again?

Comment: Why don't you try ObjectMetadata object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key),
          new File("Download location"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the file, you already know the key name and the bucket which allows constructing the S3 URL of the file uploaded.

The support for the URL attributes is not currently available in S3 API for creating objects.

Comment: I actually didn't realise that KEY was the filename!  I was putting in a security key, which was not doing anything.